# Check Mongoose model field data type in NodeJS controller

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is it possible to look up the data type of a field in a Mongoose model within a NodeJS controller?

I am building a NodeJS API in Node 12 and Mongoose 5.

I am building pagination using the mongoose-pagination-v2 plugin.

I want to dynamically generate the Mongodb query operators. The problem I am running into is I need to know the data type of the field being filtered before creating the Mongodb query operators dynamically. I would like to be able to check the model field's data type to apply the correct type of Mongo query operation.

Otherwise I am applying the incorrect type of operation to the data type. e.g `CastError: Cast to Can't use $options with Number`

Example psuedocode of what I would like to do:

```
  if (myModel[filterBy].type === 'String') { // A fake condition, I want to check the model data type here... is this possible?

    // String filtering
    const filterOperator = { [filterBy]: { "$regex": filterValue }};

  } else if (myModel[filterBy].type === 'Number') { // Is this possible?

    // Number filtering
    const filterOperator = { [filterBy]: filterValue };

  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the type from the schema
(From mongoose documentation)

```
const schema = new Schema({ name: String });
schema.paths('name') instanceof mongoose.SchemaType; // true
schema.paths('name') instanceof mongoose.Schema.Types.String; // true
schema.paths('name').instance; // 'String'
```

In your example:

```
myModel.schema.paths(filterBy).instance === 'String'
```

Comment: Thank you! Slight correction, it appears that the property name is 'paths' rather than 'path'. This is working for me: myModel.schema.paths[filterBy].instance